# Disable link on date (APS)

Tags: asp-classic

Does anyone know how to disable link based on date. For example, by 30th August the user can no more access the page..Need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Really Really basic code bout you could do something like

where you would need to change 2009 , 08, 30 to the year, month, day of the expiration date

```
Dim theDate : theDate = Now()
Dim Result : Result = false
if Year(theDate) <= 2009 then
    if Month(theDate) <= 08 then
        if Day(theDate) <= 30 then
            Result = true
        end if
    end if
end if

if Result then
    'Date is still valid do your code
else
    'Date is NOT valid do your code
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some ASP tutorials,

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_variables.asp